# Trying to generate an extension in fabfile. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: python, google-chrome-extension, fabric

This is the code I have so far and is giving me bugs.

```
path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
cmd =["js %s/pre_src/common/app/main.js" % path , "build", path]
'''local(" ".join(cmd))'''
run(path + "/pre_src/common/app/main.js -s", use_sudo=True)
```

What is the difference between local and run? How do I run the main.js? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

`local()` operates on the local machine running fabric and does not by default capture output.  `run()` operates on the remote host over ssh.  It sounds like you're trying to run something remotely that is on the local system.  To do that, you'll need to copy over the file in question first using `put()`.

I would recommend reading through the whole [tutorial](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.14/tutorial.html) to get a good introduction to what fabric does.